# Yammer API alternates responses 302 and 404

Tags: c#, html, oauth-2.0, sharepoint-2013, yammer

I'm programmatically trusting my yammer app through .NET. While debugging the POST request to trust an app, the responses can seemingly arbitrarily render either a 302 or a 404 as the response tries to redirect to a SharePoint MySite host.

If I during the same debug session loop my requests, I get the same type of response. I have to restart debugging to have a chance at a different response. I have tried setting minute long sleeps to ensure that time has nothing to do with which type of response I get. Same rule seem to apply: One debug session, one response type.

My question is now: What do I need to do to avoid these 404's?

Here's the fiddler responses:

THE 302 RESPONSE:

```
POST https://www.yammer.com/MYNETWORK/oauth2/decision?client_id=MYAPPCODE&redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2fmy.devmachine.contoso.com&response_type=code HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: www.yammer.com
Cookie: yamtrak_id=[GUID]; _workfeed_session_id=[ID]    Content-Length: 90
Expect: 100-continue

utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=[TOKEN]=&allow=Allow
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 29 Sep 2014 13:21:51 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
Status: 302 Found
Location: http://my.devmachine.contoso.com?code=[CODE]    X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Cache-Control: no-cache
P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
Set-Cookie: yamtrak_id=[ID]; path=/; expires=Tue, 29-Sep-2015 13:21:51 GMT; secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: auth_token=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT; secure
Set-Cookie: auth_token_sso=; domain=yammer.com; path=/; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT; secure
X-Date: 1411996911966
X-Runtime: 0.073263

7e
<html><body>You are being <a href="http://my.devmachine.contoso.com?code=[CODE]">redirected</a>.</body></html>
0
```

THE 404 RESPONSE:

```
POST https://www.yammer.com/MYNETWORK/oauth2/decision?client_id=MYAPPCODE&redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2fmy.devmachine.contoso.com&response_type=code HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: www.yammer.com
Cookie: yamtrak_id=[GUID]; _workfeed_session_id=[ID]
Content-Length: 90
Expect: 100-continue

utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=[TOKEN]=&allow=Allow
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 29 Sep 2014 13:26:03 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: no-cache
P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
X-Date: 1411997163223
X-Runtime: 0.068703

a45
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8,chrome=1" /> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>The page you were looking for doesn't exist (404)</title>
  <link href="/stylesheets/yamkit/yam.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      ...
      <div id="parallax-static">
      <div id="parallax-static-text">
        <h1>Oops!</h2>
        <h2>The page you were looking for could not be found.</h2>
        <a href="/" title="">Let's go back to your happy place.</a>
      </div>
      </div>
      ...
  </body>
</html>

0
```

I'm aware of the other yammer threads in this forum, and I'm using the new login_csrf_token cookie to authenticate, so that shouldn't be the issue.

Thanks for Reading! I'm grateful for any suggestion on how to solve this.

EDIT: I've tried setting another site (google) as my redirect url, but the alternating behaviour persists.

Comment: You may wish to remove your OAUTH tokens from the captures that you've posted.

Comment: The codes are useless without the necessary context, but you're right. Better safe than sorry!

Comment: Are you trying to emulate the interactive flow that is supposed to be handled by a browser? Don't do that, open a browser.

Comment: Yes. I've learnt now that I'm looking for trouble going this route. Reading Steve Peschkas posts on the subject made it at least seem like a possible solution. I just didn't want to force the users to manually accept another app (they're piling up...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it: Turns out that sometimes the authenticity token contains plus characters (+) which needs to be URL encoded. The tokens can also contain front slashes (/) but they don't trip up the succeeding call to /session or /oauth2/decision, only plus does.